# Howto display Heic files in mediaviewer?

Tags: owncloud

I wish to use the `files_mediaviewer` [app](https://github.com/owncloud/files_mediaviewer) to display my heic files, just as it displays my jpg files:

[image]

OC is latest, system is Ubuntu20.04. I have manually compiled ImageMagick7, and added support for decoding heic files:

Thumbnails are generated, however, I couldn't make this nice overlayed *mediaviewer* displaying it.

(If I click on my heic file, it's getting downloaded automatically).

Please note, I don't want to use other solutions (like gallery, or camerapreview apps). I wish to make this mediaviewer app to display the heic files too.

Comment: Assuming windows here, you need to buy the heic codec from the microsoft store. Once you have that installed, it will work with every app, including media viewer app.

Comment: "system is Ubuntu20.04"